# mat-expansion-panel to added drop down open issue

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I added **[Angular  material  mat-expansion-panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)** to **select option** ,when I click the select menu, mat-expansion-panel is auto open, anyone know how to fix that issue,

**[Stack blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qlk8bp)**

**My code**

**component.html**

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
       <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Type your name and age
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="First name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Age">
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                       (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: What is your issue? Please describe it more in detail...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have the issue you describe but i understand what you mean. What happens is that when you click on the select, you also click on the expansion panel. You can prevent this behaviour by preventing the click to pass through the select.

```
stopPropagation
```

In your HTML change the select to:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

Comment: Great Solution!, The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
<select (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
```

Comment: Your solution should be a `<mat-panel-title  (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to `mat-panel-title`

```
 <mat-panel-title  (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-prevent-opening?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html)